# Execute two query at the same time

Tags: php, mysql

I want two execute to query at the same time but I get mysql_error .

### Query

```
select L.PLesName,
       L.ELesName, 
       L.LesTotalUnit, 
       L.TheoryUnit, 
       L.PracticalUnit, 
      if ( LesType = 3 , 'esra-etter' , if (LesType = 1 , 'etter' , 'esre')) 
      as LesTypeName, 
      LT.PLesTypName,
      ES.PEduSecName,
      L.LesMinMark 
      from lessons L 
           left join LessonTypes LT on (L.LesTypCode=LT.LesTypCode) 
           left join EducationalSections ES on (L.EduSecCode=ES.EduSecCode) 
      where L.LesCode=2133004; drop table SpamLog;--
```

### Error

```
 Error description: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
 that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
 syntax to use near 'drop table SpamLog;--' at line 7
```

I test diffrence cases but I get same error.  What am I going to do ?

Thanks.

Comment: What API are you using? The standard PHP `mysql_query()`, for example, only supports one query at a time.

Comment: Of course, the real answer here is to use transactions.

Comment: Yes , i use Mysql_Query , have u a simple way for execute two query ?

Comment: Actually in this case since you're just doing a SELECT, there's no need for a transaction. Just call two queries.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The feature you're trying to use is forbidden exactly because some people used it in your exact way. http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you can't simply call `mysql_query()` twice?

e.g.

```
mysql_query("select L.PLesName, L.ELesName, L.LesTotalUnit, L.TheoryUnit, L.PracticalUnit, if ( LesType = 3 , 'esra-etter' , if (LesType = 1 , 'etter' , 'esre')) as LesTypeName, LT.PLesTypName,ES.PEduSecName,L.LesMinMark from lessons L left join LessonTypes LT on (L.LesTypCode=LT.LesTypCode) left join EducationalSections ES on (L.EduSecCode=ES.EduSecCode) where L.LesCode=2133004");
mysql_query("drop table SpamLog");
```

Since your `SELECT` statement isn't modifying anything, there's no real need to enforce grouping.

Comment: can u give me an example like my query ? Thanks

Comment: Thanks , but i want to execute two query with START TRANSACTION , Thanks again :X

Comment: Ah, okay. Edited those in too. Note that your database engine must support them (e.g. InnoDB in MySQL, or MyISAM transactional tables).

Comment: However, you shouldn't really need the transactional guarantee here, given that your first query doesn't change anything.

Comment: MySQL does not support DDL (`CREATE`, `ALTER`, `DROP TABLE` etc) within transactions.  Attempting to do so causes an implicit commit before the DDL.  The transaction here is an effective no-op.